# Programmatically change texture color for all shapes on a canvas THREE.JS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have 2 canvas on a page, each with a random number of cubes.

How do I loop through all the cube shapes in a given canvas and change their color?

I am using THREE.JS for the first time.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I think you can get all the object in a scene with `scene.children`. Loop over them, check they are a cube, change material color.

Comment: Look at the [Object3D.traverse](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/core/Object3D.traverse) methods, which can be used with your `scene` object (`scene.traverse(function(node){...});`). The documentation and examples are excellent resources for basic questions like this.